# how to perform aggregated query on relation field check top parent elasticsearch 7. want to perform aggregated query on relation fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to perform aggregation on the basis of the parent.
Say I am collection attack records the schema is like A destination could be targeted by multiple attackers and each attacker could perform multiple attacks for the schema is like.
Destination is the parent of the source and the Source is the parent of the Data.

Data -> Source -> Destination.

Now I want to get top attackers that would be ob the basis of the number of attacks.
How I could perform this type of aggregation.

Any Help would be appreciated.